# Why do I see no output from this PL/SQL block?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'd like a code sample.

I'm tryng this:

```
DECLARE
     var NUMBER;
 BEGIN
     /*N.B. for loop variables in pl/sql are new declarations, with scope only inside the loop */ 
     FOR var IN 0 .. 10 LOOP 
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(var);
     END LOOP;

     IF (var IS NULL) THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('var is null');
     ELSE
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('var is not null');
     END IF;
 END;
```

and getting no output (though I know it's not a infinite loop). *Why is this one not printing?*

edit: The not-printing code was fixed via the database manager interface.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Doesn't sound very meaningfull since normaly you try to avoid having an infinite loop in a stored proc.

Comment: I do get output: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 var is null`

Comment: Jay S's comment is almost certainly correct here-- you need to enable serveroutput before calling your PL/SQL block.

Comment: It sounds like your question has nothing do with infinite loops, except that you think that might be an explanation of why you are not seeing output.  Suggest changing the title of your question to something more appropriate, such as "Why does this PL/SQL block not produce output?".  Probably the answer from Jay S is the most relevant to your actual question.

Comment: this was two separate issues cramped (badly) into one. The not-producing-output block was eliminated. The 'fixed' question title was also edited cause it disregarded the useful answers to the loop issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A LOOP without an EXIT statement is one way to generate an infinite loop in PL/SQL

```
BEGIN
  LOOP
    null;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You could also write a WHILE loop that never ends

```
BEGIN
  WHILE( true )
  LOOP
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 5):

If your problem is that you are getting no output, then you may not have enabled DBMS OUTPUT yet.  You can do that with:

```
set serveroutput on
```

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT` with an infinite loop is illogical. Oracle does not return any output back to the client until a command (a query, an anonymous block, DDL, whatever "unit" you're trying to run) is finished, so an infinite loop would never give you output regardless of whether you enabled it or not.

Answer (score 3):

A loop containing a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE will not be infinite (if serveroutput is enabled) as, eventually, it will fill the entire output buffer or the available memory. The limit used to be about 1 million bytes so would get hit quite quickly. If it goes to fill up the entire computer memory, that can take quite some time.

On infinite loops, I went through a bad patch of forgetting to go to the next element in a table.

```
DECLARE
  type typ_tab is table of varchar2(10) index by pls_integer;
  t_tab typ_tab;
  v_ind number;
BEGIN
  t_tab(10) := 'A';
  t_tab(20) := 'B';
  v_ind := t_tab.first;
  WHILE v_ind IS NOT NULL LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(t_tab(v_ind));
    v_ind := t_tab.next(v_ind); --Forget this and it loops forever
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Once they get into such a loop, the session may need to be killed by the DBA.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why would you need it, but:

```
BEGIN
        WHILE  1 = 1
        LOOP
                NULL;
        END LOOP;
END;
```